# Cambiar mensaje de excepción en Vaadin

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin

¿Alguien conoce el framework **VAADIN** ? tengo un problema con las alertas que muestra el framework, tengo campos tipo `Date` para seleccionar una fecha del calendario pero si digito datos `string` y oprimo el botón buscar muestra un mensaje de error que dice:

> Date Format not Reconized es decir que no reconoce el formato.

¿Alguien conoce cómo podría cambiar ese mensaje por uno en Español?

[Captura de pantalla guardada en Google Drive:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7PGy9XAmXC1WVhwS0VlNklMZm8) 
[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: Esa ! indica que se produjo una excepción para que quieres que se vea en español? (el usuario no debería de ver este tipo de cosas) poniendo un try{}catch() podrías llegar a enviar un mensaje a pantalla para indicar eso mismo con un mensaje propio, de todas formas podrías poner tu códido asi te podríamos ayudar a evitar esa excepcion, pienso que es la forma en la que recoges el valor del objeto ese (no recuerdo el nombre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Establecer el valor de un DateField a lo DateField.toString() devuelve provoca un "formato de fecha no reconocido" excepción. Debería ser posible asignar una cadena a la DateField, según lo sugerido por la interfaz de Propiedad (setValue). También debería funcionar si se utiliza un formato de fecha personalizado.

Prueba simple:

```
    DateField df = new DateField("My date", new Date());
    df.setValue(df.getValue().toString());
```